# Java Graphics Window/Canvas not showing full hexagonal grid vertically

Tags: java, canvas, graphics

For an assignment, I was to draw a hexagonal grid. I was able to get it, however the window would only show the top 2 rows (out of 7) horizontally, but would not show it all vertically. The grid is not fully shown in the window and I am wondering why it's doing that.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class hex extends Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new hex();
    }

    public hex(){  //the class for the frame, also to close the application
        super("hex");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);}
        });
        setSize(600,400);
        add("Center", new CvHex());
        show();
    }  
}

class CvHex extends Canvas{
    int centerX, centerY;
    float pixelSize, rWidth = 10.0F, rHeight = 10.0F, xP = 1000000, yP;

    CvHex() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
                xP = fx(evt.getX()); yP = fy(evt.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        });
     }

     void initgr(){
        Dimension d = getSize();
        int maxX = d.width-1, maxY = d.height-1;
        pixelSize = Math.max(rWidth/maxX, rHeight/maxY);
        centerX = maxX/2; centerY = maxY/2; 
    }
    int iX(float x){    return 
            Math.round(centerX + x/pixelSize);} //114

    float fx(int x){    
        return (x-centerX)*pixelSize;}

    int iY(float y){  
        return Math.round(centerY - y/pixelSize);}

    float fy(int y){    
        return (centerY - y)*pixelSize;   }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
        initgr();
        int left = iX(-rWidth/2), right = iX(rWidth/2), bottom = iY(-rHeight/2),
                top = iY(rHeight/2), xMiddle = iX(0), yMiddle = iY(0);

        //to rotate to flat
        right = ((right - xMiddle)/2) + xMiddle;
        left = ((xMiddle - left)/2) + left;
        top = ((yMiddle - top)/2) + top;
        bottom = ((bottom - yMiddle)/2) + yMiddle;

        int side = (right - xMiddle)/2; 

        int rightmost = (int)sqrt((side * side) + (yMiddle * yMiddle));
        rightmost = (rightmost/2) + right;
        int leftmost = side;
        leftmost = left - (2*leftmost);

        int totalL = rightmost - leftmost;

        //for the offset (side) hexagon
            int lM, rM, sTop, sBottom, sY, sLeft, sRight;
            sTop = yMiddle; //should be good
            sBottom = yMiddle * 2; //should be good
            lM = right; //good
            sY = bottom; //good
            sLeft = rightmost; //good

            sRight = rightmost + (4*side);

            int length = sLeft - lM; 
            rM = sRight + length;

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

            //first hexagon
            g.drawLine(right, top, rightmost, yMiddle);
            g.drawLine(right, bottom, rightmost, yMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, top, leftmost, yMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, bottom, leftmost, yMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, bottom, right, bottom);  //x, y, w, h
            g.drawLine(right, top, left, top);

            //for the bottom hexagon
            int dMiddle = yMiddle * 2;
            int dTop = bottom;
            int dBottom = bottom * 2;

            g.drawLine(right, dTop, rightmost, dMiddle);
            g.drawLine(right, dBottom, rightmost, dMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, dTop, leftmost, dMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, dBottom, leftmost, dMiddle);
            g.drawLine(left, dBottom, right, dBottom);  //x, y, w, h
            g.drawLine(right, dTop, left, dTop);

            //offset right
            leftmost = rightmost + (4*side);
            left = right + totalL;
            right = left + (4*side);
            rightmost = right + length;
        }

    //for the offset side column
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){

            g.drawLine(sRight, sTop, rM, sY);
            g.drawLine(sRight, sBottom, rM, sY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, sTop, lM, sY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, sBottom, lM, sY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, sBottom, sRight, sBottom);  //x, y, w, h
            g.drawLine(sRight, sTop, sLeft, sTop);

            int oY = sY * 2;
            int oTop = sBottom;
            int oBottom = sBottom * 2;

            g.drawLine(sRight, oTop, rM, oY);
            g.drawLine(sRight, oBottom, rM, oY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, oTop, lM, oY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, oBottom, lM, oY);
            g.drawLine(sLeft, oBottom, sRight, oBottom);  //x, y, w, h
            g.drawLine(sRight, oTop, sLeft, oTop);

            //offset right
            lM = rM + (4*side);
            sLeft = sRight + totalL;
            sRight = sLeft + (4*side);
            rM = sRight + length;
        }

     }
}
```

This is what I am speaking about.
Regular: [image: Regular pop-out]

Stretched across: [image: across]

**Vertically stretched, just scales regular as it should but not showing all the shapes as I want it to**: [image: stretched vertically but nothing changes except that it scales the original window instead of fitting all the shapes as I want it to]

I've looked on here and elsewhere what could remedy it but the solutions I found are with Graphics2d and swing, jFrame, etc. Things I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff wrong with your scaling code here- way too much to look through especially during the line drawing phase. I ran it and it completely deforms if the x value is very small so I can't correct it without rewriting it completely.

Some hints:

- Make sure you scale the x distance and y distance independently, unless the hexagons must be symmetrical then calculate the *min* and go from there.
- Don't bother using the center (unless you need a symmetrical/infinite grid). Break the entire screen into X columns and Y rows and use that as your width/length.
- Once you have the width & length and the top-left corner, you can just make the hexagon from there from the top-left corner

  ```
  top-left + width/3
  top-left + 2*width/3
  top-left + width + height/2, etc
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but when you mean make x distance and y distance scale independently, you mean my maxX and maxy? independent from the window?

Comment: I mean the pixelScale value. If you want the hexagonal grid to exactly fit the screen, the hex width must match the screen width and vice versa. You need to elaborate on your requirements.